# How to create multiple subclasses from a list in python?

Tags: python, subclass

I'm trying to get my data in an hierarchical way, so I decided to turn to subclasses. The file I'm getting the data from is formatted like this:

```
2WQZ_chain_A
Score = 338.0
53-164
208-317
327-595
611-654

2WQZ_chain_B
Score = 344.0
53-164
205-317
327-595
611-655

2XB6_chain_A
Score = 319.0
64-163
211-317
327-596
613-654

2XB6_chain_B
Score = 329.0
53-163
212-317
327-596
613-654
```

And what I want to obtain is a first class called as the PDB name (i.e: 2WQZ) with the subclasses called chain_A, chain_B and so on. These subclasses should contain an object called "score" and a third subclass called "intervals" containing the possibles intervals. The general idea is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kvyg.png).

At the moment I tried using a dictionary but ended up with the correct PDB class, but only the second chain, my code is

```
class PDB(object):
    def __init__(self, pdbname):
        self.pdbid = pdbname

class Chain(PDB):
    def __init__(self, chainame,  score, pdbname):
        self.chainid = chainame
        self.score = score
        super().__init__(pdbname)



making_class = open("covered_intervals.txt", "r").readlines()

pdblist = []

for i in making_class:
    if "chain" in i:
        pdblist.append(i[:4])

pdblist = list(dict.fromkeys(pdblist))
pdblist2 = dict.fromkeys(pdblist)

for i in pdblist:
    pdblist2[i] = PDB(i)
    for j in making_class:
        if i in j:
            chainame = j[5:12]
            pdblist2[i] = Chain(chainame, 4, i)
```

4 is a placeholder, and I see why I get only the last chain, but have no idea how to get the two chains under the same PDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, a dictionary can be created for top nodes, and since It is a fixed depth tree,  class nesting is not required. Chain Class will have three components

1. Chain Name
2. Score
3. List of Ranges - I have implemented a class for range

```
class Chain():
    def __init__(self, chainame,  score=None):
        self.chainid = chainame
        self.score = score
        self.ranges=[]

    def add_range(self, range):
        self.ranges.append(range)

    def add_score(self, score):
        self.score = score


class range1():
    def __init__(self, str):
        x = str.split("-")
        self.start = int(x[0])
        self.end = int(x[1])

counter = 0
pdb = ""
ch = None
data = {}

with open("covered_intervals.txt", "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.strip()=="":
            counter=0
            x = data.get(pdb, [])
            x.append(ch)
            data[pdb] = x
        elif counter==0:
            x = line.split("_", 1)
            pdb = x[0]
            chainname = x[1]
            ch = Chain(chainname)
            counter  = counter +1
        elif counter==1:
            ch.add_score(float(line.split("=")[1]))
            counter = counter +1
        else:
            ch.add_range(range1(line))
        line = f.readline()

if counter != 0:
    x = data.get(pdb, [])
    x.append(ch)
    data[pdb] = x
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! Just a little note: there's a mistake in the range1 class. As you wrote it it prints only the first and second character of the interval that's is being considerated (i.e: 53-164 becomes 5 and 3).  
self.start = int(str[0]) and self.end = int(str[1]) should be  self.start = int(x[0]) and self.end = int(x[1])

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest creating something, that can parse one textblock from the file into usable variables, for example like this:

```
def parse_block(lines):
    pdb_name = lines[0][:4]
    chain = lines[0][5:]
    score = lines[1].split("=")[1].strip()
    intervals = lines[2:]
    return (pdb_name, chain, score, intervals)
```

Using this, you could build your classes, or use a nested dictionary, which would fit the data structure well, too.

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("pdbdata", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

pdb_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for block in content.split("\n\n"):
    pdb_name, chain, score, intervals = parse_block(block.splitlines())
    pdb_dict[pdb_name][chain] = {"score": score, "intervals": intervals}
```

The resulting nested dict looks like this:

```
{'2WQZ': {'chain_A': {'intervals': ['53-164', '208-317', '327-595', '611-654'],
                      'score': '338.0'},
          'chain_B': {'intervals': ['53-164', '205-317', '327-595', '611-655'],
                      'score': '344.0'}},
 '2XB6': {'chain_A': {'intervals': ['64-163', '211-317', '327-596', '613-654'],
                      'score': '319.0'},
          'chain_B': {'intervals': ['53-163', '212-317', '327-596', '613-654'],
                      'score': '329.0'}}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could you elaborate a bit on how to actually make the correct subclasses? I'm pretty new to the topic

Comment: @FrancescoOliva I don't think inheritance is the right tool here. You could make independent classes with the attributes they need and use composition to connect them. For example the `PDB` class could have an attribute `chains`, that is a list of `Chain` objects.